# HDInsight Installation failure

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to install Microsoft HDInsight Emulator for Windows Azure using the Web Platform Installer 5.0. The installation fails while installing Hortonworks Data Platform. The following are the part of logs after installation:

```
CAQuietExec:  Checking JAVA_HOME is set correctly...
CAQuietExec:  'C:\Azul\zulu1.7.0_65-7.6.0.1-win64\bin\java -version 2>&1 | findstr /i "version"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
CAQuietExec:  operable program or batch file.
CAQuietExec:  "1.6.0_31" was unexpected at this time.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x800700ff: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x800700ff: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction CheckPreReq returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
```

I have checked that JAVA_HOME is set in environment variables to `C:\Azul\zulu1.7.0_65-7.6.0.1-win64.` When I run the command `'C:\Azul\zulu1.7.0_65-7.6.0.1-win64\bin\java -version 2>&1 | findstr /i "version"'` in command prompt, It returns the result with the version `1.7.0_65`.
I don't understand why in the log this command is not recognized while I am able to execute it and from where `1.6.0_31` version came in log?
Could you please help me to resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Destrif thanks for suggesting edits

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the failure. It was that command was wrapped in single quotes by installer and command prompt was not recognising it. After replacing single quotes with double quotes I am not getting this error.